# How to convert character variable to numeric date variable

Tags: sas

I have below variable

```
mhstdtc
-----------    
2011-01-01
2015-02-01
2002
2001
2003-03
2003-12
```

Here is my code I used to convert the variable

```
ASTDTMC=INPUT(MHSTDTC,is8601da.);
PUT ASTDTMC DATE9.;
```

It worked only the variable has yyyy-mm-dd values, remaining were returned blank. Please help me to convert yyyy and yyyy-mm values also;

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You will need to figure a scheme to impute missing month and day.

Answer (score 0):

One way using SUBSTR on the left.

```
25         data _null_;
26            input iso :$10.;
27            mask = '....-06-15';
28            substr(mask,1,length(iso))=iso;
29            ASTDTM=INPUT(mask,is8601da.);
30            format astdtm date9.;
31            put 'NOTE: ' (_all_)(=);
32            cards;

NOTE: iso=2011-01-01 mask=2011-01-01 ASTDTM=01JAN2011
NOTE: iso=2015-02-01 mask=2015-02-01 ASTDTM=01FEB2015
NOTE: iso=2002 mask=2002-06-15 ASTDTM=15JUN2002
NOTE: iso=2001 mask=2001-06-15 ASTDTM=15JUN2001
NOTE: iso=2003-03 mask=2003-03-15 ASTDTM=15MAR2003
NOTE: iso=2003-12 mask=2003-12-15 ASTDTM=15DEC2003
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have your original dates in character format, add "01-01" to each date, then do the conversion. If your dates are not in character format, convert them to character then add "01-01" to them, and try this code :

```
data have ;
 input mhstdtc $10.;
cards;
2011-01-01
2015-02-01
2002
2001
2003-03
2003-12
;

data want;
set have;
ASTDTMC2=compress(catx("",MHSTDTC,"-01-01")," ","");
ASTDTMC3=inPUT(ASTDTMC2,yymmdd10.);
run;
```

The result is in ASTDTMC3.

```
18628
20120
15341
14976
15765
16040
```